# Extract certifcates from output of "openssl s_client"

Tags: awk, openssl

I would like to get all certificates of the certicate chain of a http-site.
Using openssl I connect to the http-site and store output to file **out.txt**:

```
openssl s_client -connect www.openssl.org:443 -showcerts > out.txt
```

The content of **out.txt** looks like below. It contains two certificates:

```
...
 0 s:CN = www.openssl.org
   i:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIFVTCCBD2gAwIBAgISAwk9QUiwVmoQAtcCLKybaK7yMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUA
...
mQBom1EISBOiNyu5koR6iRZcXsn6x/4kwA==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
   i:O = Digital Signature Trust Co., CN = DST Root CA X3
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIIEkjCCA3qgAwIBAgIQCgFBQgAAAVOFc2oLheynCDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQsFADA/
...
KOqkqm57TH2H3eDJAkSnh6/DNFu0Qg==
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
---
...
```

Now I want to store every certificate in a file ending with extension **.cer**.
For the above example the files **Let's Encrypt Authority X3.cer** and **www.openssl.org.cer** should be created.

Using command **openssl x509** I was only able to store first certifcate contained in **out.txt**.

```
cat out.txt | openssl x509 > www.openssl.org.cer
```

But I want to store all *certifcates* contained in **out.txt** not just the first one.

Can this be done with **openssl** somehow ? Or with **awk** ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this can be done with awk. I would like to present my solution piece by piece.

#### Step 1: extract everything between "BEGIN CERTIFICATE" and "END CERTIFICATE"

Only write lines between "BEGIN CERTIFICATE" and "END CERTIFICATE" to output:

```
awk '
/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,/END CERTIFICATE/ {
print $0
}
' out.txt
```

#### Step 2: extract line containing CN

selects line which contains CN (e.g.  0 s:CN = www.openssl.org)

```
awk '
/^ [0-9]+ s:.*CN = / {
print $0
}
' out.txt
```

This yields output:

```
 0 s:CN = www.openssl.org
 1 s:C = US, O = Let's Encrypt, CN = Let's Encrypt Authority X3
```

#### Step 3: extract content of field CN

```
awk '
BEGIN {
# change field separator, so that $2 returns everything after "CN = "
FS="CN = "
}
# selects line which contains CN (e.g.  0 s:CN = www.openssl.org)
/^ [0-9]+ s:.*CN = / {
# use CN (e.g. www.openssl.org) as filename
print $2
}
' out.txt
```

This yields output:

```
www.openssl.org
Let's Encrypt Authority X3
```

#### Step 4: Full Solution

This creates files **Let's Encrypt Authority X3.cer** and **www.openssl.org.cer**:

```
awk '
BEGIN {
# change field separator, so that $2 returns everything after "CN = "
FS="CN = "
}
# selects line which contains CN (e.g.  0 s:CN = www.openssl.org)
/^ [0-9]+ s:.*CN = / {
# use CN (e.g. www.openssl.org) as filename
filename=$2".cer"
}
# write all lines between "BEGIN CERTIFICATE" and "END CERTIFICATE" to filename
/BEGIN CERTIFICATE/,/END CERTIFICATE/ {
print $0 > filename
}
' out.txt
```

**AWK Documentation:**
https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/index.html

Comment: This is almost perfect. One question, though - what if `CN = ` is not the last one? In my case `$2` matches **Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net), emailAddress = support@zscaler.com** instead of **Zscaler Intermediate Root CA (zscalertwo.net)**.

Comment: I replaced `filename=$2".cer"` with `split($2,cn,","); gsub(/"/, "", cn[1]); filename=cn[1]".crt"`
Not sure if this is the idiomatic way to do it in awk.